# Iterate or map custom functions over tibble of arguments

Tags: r, tidyverse, apply, purrr

I have some analysis code which I reuse on multiple chunks of data with different settings. I have modularized this process such that I can specify the settings and data to analyze by defining some variables, then calling the analysis code, something like this:

```
## Specify settings
input_var <- "foo"  # these are string parameters fed into various custom functions in the analysis code
dep_var <- "bar"
other_var <- "baz"
some_setting <- "Ni"
label <- "peng"
target_data <- list(neewom)   # this is a data tibble

## Call analysis code
## These include references to the settings variables specified above
source("first_analysis.R")
source("additional_analyses.R")
source("process_outputs.R")
```

As modularization goes, for testing the analysis on various configurations of data and settings, this works fine.

However, I'd like to be able to run this workflow on many different combinations of data and settings at once without duplicating the code every time.

My approach is to put all the setting specifications into a tibble, with the setting variables as the column names, e.g.

```
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  input_var dep_var other_var some_setting label target_data     
  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>     <chr>        <chr> <list>          
1 foo       bar     baz       Ni           peng  <tibble [5 × 2]>

## Additional rows as needed to contain other configurations of settings
```

I feel like there must be a way for me to use `map` or `apply` or something similar to then run the analysis code on each row, if necessary wrapping the analysis code in a function, e.g.

```
run_analysis <- function(input_var, dep_var, other_var, some_setting, label, target_data) {
    source("first_analysis.R")
    source("additional_analyses.R")
    source("process_outputs.R")
}
```

But I can't wrap my head around how to go about doing that. First because `map` (or `map2`) only allow one (or two) arguments respectively, and I have more than that; second because I'm not sure if the specific variables in each column need to be assigned to their respective names as an intermediate step (or how to do that). I could do it by looping over one row at a time, but is there a vectorised way to do it?

Comment: Have a look at `purrr::pmap` for more than 2 arguments.